# How to query on an array?

Tags: apache-drill

I have an object like this in drill:

```
{MyFruit: [{name:Mike, age:10},{name:Jacob,age:9},{name:William, age:6}]}
```

I can get "Mike" by doing:

```
Select MyFruit[0].name
```

Is there a way for me to get the list of every single "name"? I tried the following and it does not like it:

```
Select MyFruit[*].name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this fruits.json file:

```
{"MyFruit": [{"name":"Mike", "age":10},{"name":"Jacob","age":9},{"name":"William", "age":6}]}
```

The Drill statement is:

```
select t.flatdata.name from (select flatten(MyFruit) as flatdata from dfs.`/Users/path/fruits.json`) t;
+----------+
|  EXPR$0  |
+----------+
| Mike     |
| Jacob    |
| William  |
+----------+
3 rows selected (0.14 seconds)
```

You need to use a subquery that flattens the complex nesting and table aliases, t and flatdata, that resolve ambiguities.